# Is there a function to get the message object or a message from a view attached to it, in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a subclass of `discord.ui.View` that should disable all buttons on timeout among other things, I know of the [discord.Interaction.original_response()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=original_response#discord.Interaction.original_response) function, however it appears to actually fetch the response an interaction within the view made.

I checked the documentation the best i could but i still couldn't find a viable solution
Here's my class here:

```py
class View(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, original_interaction, timeout=180, **kwargs):
        self.original_interaction = original_interaction # interaction object from an app command
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout, **kwargs)

    def disable(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'disabled') and not hasattr(obj, 'url'):
            obj.disabled = True

    async def on_timeout(self):
        await self.disable_all()

    async def disable_all(self):
        [self.disable(i) for i in self.children]
        if self.message:
            await self.message.edit(view=self) # the message in question:

    # the rest ...
```

Interaction.original_response() is a coroutine, and i can only run it after having sent the message - and i can't pass it in at that point. I have also tried using it with the original_interaction object, to no avail

```py
view = View(self, interaction)
await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=view)
view.message = await interaction.original_response() # i can't do this anymore
```